# Check If Arduino has FET

Tags: arduino

I have read that Arduino can be powered by both 12v from dc jack and from USB as it is equipped with FET which takes power from only one input. At the same time I read that many people destroyed their arduino as they were not equipped with FET. How do I know if mine has one? Basically I want to power from 12v and open Serial Monitor on USB.

Comment: What arduino model do you have? The arduino uno and some others accept 5v to 12v. Your best bet is to check the arduino site. See the "tech specs" tab here: https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3.

Comment: @JustinBuchanan I just wanted to confirm If I can connect both USB and 12v at same time? 12v + 5v

Comment: *I just wanted to confirm If I can connect both USB and 12v at same time?* This depends on the model of Arduino and what the schematic of that model is. There is no straight answer unless we **exactly** know the design. Also explain **why** you need to power the Arduino from 12 V when you already have a 5 V available through USB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of Arduino with FET:

[image]

Check if you can find a similar component or add a clear picture of your board so we can assist you with it. Or just indicate the type and version.